# AS3: anti alias animation by code

Tags: actionscript-3, antialiasing

So what parameters in the Advanced anti alias are close to the "animation" preset in the Flash IDE?

I need to animate a bunch of texts (translation and rotation) and setting sharpness and thickness doesn't seem to help with the sub pixel rendering...

Answer (score 3):

I think you're after the [`.gridFitType`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#gridFitType) property.

> The type of grid fitting used for this text field. This property applies only if the flash.text.AntiAliasType property of the text field is set to `flash.text.AntiAliasType.ADVANCED`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that property. The letters keep "jumping" even with GridFitType.SUBPIXEL enabled... so far the best results have been  ironically with AntiAliasType.NORMAL ... but still not there.

Comment: @Pier Interesting. Admittedly I don't have much experience with TextField as I use sprite sheet fonts - maybe give that a go for animated text?

Comment: Do you have some class that handles the sprite sheet creation / using?

Comment: @Pier Not at the office, but I'll whip something up for you later on. Alternatively I think a quick Google will get you some relevant results :)

Comment: @Pier Worth noting at this stage that `Starling` uses bitmap fonts.

Answer (score 1):

When I use the sharpness, I almost always put it at the maximum 255.

I would recommend you draw your TextField to a BitmapData object, then rotate the BitmapData.

```
    var myTextHolder:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myText.width,myText.height,true,0x00000000);
```

myTextHolder.draw(myText);

If you want to make the text really crisp, I would suggest:

1. creating the text twice as large as you need
2. put it in a bitmapdata
3. on each frame, rotate the bitmapdata
4. then shrink the bitmapdata back down to normal size
5. draw the result on the screen

I beleive you can use the Matrix class to perform all the operations you need here - translation, rotation, and scaling.

Comment: How is that better than cacheAsBitmap?

Comment: I'm not saying it's better, that's just how i would do it. I actually like marty wallace's answer a bit better, and gave it a vote.